# Showing Prompt in MVVM WP7 application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have a main ViewModel and a UserLoginViewModel. From the User view model I need to show a prompt with Ok/Cancel options. I've done it as stated in this link  http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/WPF-MVVM-e28093-Simple-e28098MessageBoxShowe28099-With-Action-Func.aspx . To avoid Invalid-cross thread exception i used a dispatcher. The code is something like this

```
  mainDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MessageBoxDelegate
                  (
                      (message, title) => { Popup(msg, ""); }
                  ), messageArgs);
```

where mainDispatcher is the dispatcher of MainView and Popup is of type  `Func<string, string, MessageBoxResult>`

And it works fine. The problem is that I cannot get the results from the `BeginInvoke` Method. Is there is any way to get the result from the `BeginInvoke` method? 
If is there is not, any suggestions how i can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you get the result with a *var result = Popup(msg, "");*

You need to evaluate the result within BeginInvoke() because any code below BeginInvoke() runs before BeginInvoke().

Comment: The BeginInvoke methode returns an object of type  DispatcherOperation which does not contains any result.

Comment: You don't care for the result of BeginInvoke. You care for the result of Popup(). You get and evaluate this result INSIDE BeginInvoke.

Comment: Thank you , that solved my problem. I used a callback function and made the thread waiting until getting the result

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how it fits into the MVVM model, but I would suggest you to use the code4fun's [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt) instead of a MessageBox

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , I'll have a look at code4fun's MessagePrompt.  But still my question is unanswered